# VHDL frequency divider code

Tags: vhdl

I have this code:

```
architecture Behavioral of BlockName is
  signal t: std_logic;
  signal c : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
begin
  process (reset, clk) begin
    if (reset = '1') then
      t <= '0';
      c <= (others=>'0');
    elsif clk'event and clk='l' then
      if (c = din) then
        t <= NOT(t);
        c <= (others=>'0');
      else
        c <= c + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
  dout <= t;
end Behavioral;
```

This code's role is to divide the frequency when it gets input (clock + value) and outputs a divided frequency.

Now my questions:

1. What does this `c <= (others=>'0');` mean ?
2. What value does t get here `t <= NOT(t);` ? the last t value?  does the `<=` work as `=` ?

Comment: Just paste the code here, don't make it an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `c <= (others=>'0');` is equivalent to `c <= "00";`
2. `t <= not(t);` assigns to `t` the opposite of the current value in `t`.
3. `=` is an equality comparison in VHDL.
4. `<=` is signal assignment in VHDL.

Comment: `c <= (others=>'0');`  is an assignment statement with a right hand side expression that is an array [aggregate](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00002.htm)  with type and length supplied by context, the value dependent on *association* of array elements with element values. `others` as a choice stands here for every element of a std_logic_vector with the length of `c` and this expression associates the value '0' with every element of that std_logic_vector. The subtype (index range constraint) will be converted to the the subtype of `c` during assignment.

Comment: `NOT` is a unary logic operator [which has the highest priority](http://vhdl.renerta.com/source/vhd00047.htm). Parentheses around `t` are not necessary here. "<=" is a compound delimiter, a lexical element required as part of a signal assignment statement. It's also used as an operator name for the  'less than or equal` relational operator. "=" is also the equality relational operator. In VHDL signal assignment is via [signal assignment](http://vhdl.renerta.com/source/vhd00063.htm) statement not through an operator. Operators perform functions on operands of a type returning a value of a type.

Answer (score 0):

since 'C' is taken as a vector and to store every bit of it with zero 'c <= (others=>'0');' was used and the concept of blocking and non blocking signals is not present in VHDL. here '=' is used to compare and '<=' is used to assign the signal.
In the your code 't' is declared as a signal and a signal will be updated at the end of the every iteration of the process block. so  in the statement 't <= NOT(t);' the value of the t is still the old value and will be updated at the end of the current simulation tick.